# how to toggle a div on click at different div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle a div by clicking on a different div. The only relation that two divs share is that they are inside the same div. I have a `DIV class comment` which holds `DIV class button` that is supposed to toggle `DIV class box` when clicked. The `box` DIV is also inside the `comment` DIV. I am trying to use `jQuery(this).find(".box").toggle();`, but it is not working. I am triggering it with `$( ".button" ).click(function()`. The script is currently at the bottom of my body.

Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here? I've been playing around with the function for a while now, but with no luck at all. Thank you in advance for your replies.

[JSFIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/w3sCg/3/)

### HTML

```
<div class="comment">
    <div class="button">
        show/hide .box with text1
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        text 1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="comment">
    <div class="button">
        show/hide .box with text2
    </div>

    <div class="box">
        text 2
    </div>
<div>
```

### jQuery

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
    jQuery(this).find(".box").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Updated answer with prolly more explanation than you want, but should give you full idea of what is going on and how to make better use of this information in the future. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In short, change:

```
jQuery(this).find(".box").toggle();
```

To ***ONE*** of the following lines:

```
$(this).parent('.comment').find(".box").toggle();
$(this).closest('.comment').find(".box").toggle();
$(this).siblings(".box").toggle();
```

---

### Full Explanation:

The reason it's not working is due to the call. Let's break down your call and see what exactly it's doing.

First we see a simple jQuery [**`selector`**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). This tells jQuery to look for a div containing the class `button`. Keep in mind, jQuery makes use of any CSS selector. So selecting an item in jQuery is as simple as using it's CSS selector!

```
$( ".button" )
```

Next you are assigning an event. In this case, that event is `click`, meaning you're telling a `div` having the class `button` to do something every time it is `clicked`. Keep in mind, however, not including a callback function is an easy way to `trigger` this event as well.

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
```

Now this next line is where your `mistake` takes place.

```
jQuery(this).find(".box").toggle();
```

The first mistake is the use of `jQuery.` after you're already making use of it's short sign, `$`. You only need use the elongated name if you are using jQuery's `noconflict` because another JS library you include might use `$`. In other words, if `$('.button')` works and is a jQuery object when used, then you don't need to use `jQuery.`. See more about this [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

Now, that aside, we can look at `jQuery(this)` as `$(this)`. Whenever you use [**`$(this)`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this) in an Event's `callback` method, you're referring to ***the element that the event was tied too***. That means that `$(this)` in your function refers to `$('.button')`. The problem here is that you then want it to find an **inner** element containing the class `box`. Well according to your HTML, that can't happen since `.box` is a sibling, it is not within the **inner** HTML of `.button`. Thus you need to make a different call before you can find `.box`.

There are actually several solutions here. No solution is more "correct" than another, just simply different and possibly causes a different amount of "time" to run. Now I went with what I saw as being the most simple in that it gives you control over the `parent` element which contains ALL relevant elements to this function.  I'll talk about possible alternatives in a minute.

```
$(this).closest('.comment')
```

The above line simply tells `.button:clicked` to look for the first parent element that contains the class `.comment`. In other words, this won't find any children or siblings, it will only go up from the current element. This allows us to grab the block that contains all relevant elements and information and thus make maneuvers as needed. So, in the future, you might even use this as a variable in the function, such as:

```
$('.button').click(function(e) {
    var container = $(this).closest('.comment');
```

Now you can `find` anything within this element block. In this case you want to `find` box and `toggle` it. Thus:

```
$(this).closest('.comment').find(".box").toggle();
//  Or with our variable I showed you
container.find(".box").toggle();
```

Now, there are plenty of alternatives based on your HTML layout. This example I've given would be good even if `.box` was buried inside more elements inside `.comment`, however, given your exact HTML, we see that `.button` and `.box` are [**siblings**](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/). This means that you could make this call different entirely and get the same result using something like:

```
$(this).siblings(".box").toggle();
```

This will allow our currently clicked and selected `button` element to look for ANY and ALL [**siblings**](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) having class `box`. This is a great solution and simple if your HTML is that simple.

However, many times, for "comment" type setups, our HTML is not so simple, nor is it [**`static`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174530/difference-between-dynamically-created-li-tag-vs-static). It's usually something loaded **after** the page load. This means our general assignment of `.click` will not work. Given your exact HTML and not knowing a static Parent **ID**, I would probably write your code as:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button', function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.box').toggle();
});
```

What this does is allow for this `click event` to be assigned to ANY element containing `.button` for a class, whether loaded with page or even ten minutes after the page is up. However, the caveat often seen here is the assignment is placed on `document`. Should we assign a lot of events to `document` it could become quite convoluted and possibly slow down the client's browser. Not to mention the arguments held over all the other headaches this could cause. So here's my recommendation, make a `static` (loads with page, is a part of page's main HTML) loading area and do our `dynamic assignment` to that. For instance:

```
<div id"Comments"><!-- load comments --></div>
```

Then you can do the assignment as such:

```
$('#Comments').on('click', '.button', function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.box').toggle();
});
```

If you have any more questions, just comment!

> *Side Note* `.on` is for jQuery versions 1.7+. If using older jQuery, use `.live` or `.bind`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery selector `.siblings()` to re-write your function like this:

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3sCg/4/) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is this:

```
  $(this).parent().find(".box").toggle();
```